# Intercept nginx reply body and change status code

Tags: nginx

I have some internal API server `api.example.com` which, upon a certain kind of request, returns a web page containing either `yes` or `no` with status code `200` in both cases (and I have no control over this server).

I am trying to setup an nginx configuration available on `frontend.example.com` which will proxy `frontend.example.com/foobar` to `api.example.com`, and I would like to reply to the query with either `200` upon `yes`, or `4xx` upon `no` — say `400` to keep it simple here. I don't particularly care about the response body, as this will be used by scripts only. I would like the setup to be self-contained, and for this reason, I'd rather have no external script/website/proxy do the job; ie. I'd like to do this entirely in nginx configuration (preferably without non-stock module).

To sum up, I would somehow need some kind of predicate over the *returned web page content* which would enable me to write something like

```
if ($webpage_content = "yes") {
    return 400;
}
```

I haven't found any documentation for that. Is there any way to do such a thing?

Thanks!